# Check if each level of object exists

Tags: c#

Lets consider an example model as below.

```
class student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public school SchoolName { get; set; }
}

class school
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

student student1 = new student();
```

As we all know that we access school name as below.

```
Console.WriteLine(student1.SchoolName.Name);
```

If `school` is not assigned to a `student`, `student1.SchoolName` will be null. So the above `Console.WriteLine()` fails.

I end up writing a `if` statement for all such elements, which is a pain in the a$$. Do we have an alternate way to handle these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we have to do explicit `null` checking for previous versions to `C#`

in `C#` `6.0` we have [`Null-Conditional`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn986595.aspx) operator `?`

This operator does exactly what you are looking, if the left side of the operator is null, it cascades a null of the resulting type to the right.

So you could do this.

```
Console.WriteLine(student1.SchoolName?.Name);
```

In short, if you replace your `.` with the null conditional operator `?.` it will cascade the null down the line:

Check this [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zpN2Dq)

Comment: Try using Roslyn in the fiddle.

Comment: try this for before C# 6.0, 
Console.WriteLine(student1.SchoolName == null) ? "" : student1.SchoolName.Name

Comment: Thanks all. Works in C# 6.0

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(student1.SchoolName?.Name);
```

if SchoolName is null, then Name property will not be evaluated.

Comment: For methods that doesn't handle null values, it can be extended to student1.SchoolName?.Name??defaultValue

Comment: Note that this is a C# 6.0 syntax and OP might be using an older version.

Comment: try this: 
Console.WriteLine(student1.SchoolName == null) ? "" : student1.SchoolName.Name;

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of C#(before c# 6) You can try with conditional operator:

```
Console.WriteLine(student1.SchoolName !=null? student1.SchoolName.Name:string.empty);
```

Comment: ternary operator is kind of if.

Comment: Yeah, but writing multiple lines and blocks using if, its just simple writing in one line.

Answer (score 1):

Few other options for you:

1.Define the property `SchoolName` like this:

```
private school _SchoolName;
public school SchoolName
{
    get
    {
        if (_SchoolName == null)
            return new school() { ID = 0, Name = string.empty };
        else
            return _SchoolName;
    }
    set { _SchoolName = value; }
}
```

2.Check for null before print the value

```
Console.WriteLine(student1.SchoolName ==null?string.empty: student1.SchoolName.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of C# before 6.0, then you could use a [Ternary Operatory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(student1.SchoolName == null ? string.empty : student1.SchoolName.Name);
```

Alternatively, a `[Null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn986595.aspx)' would do the trick:

```
Console.WriteLine(student1.SchoolName?.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is like this:

```
class student
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(...)]
    public virtual school School { get; set; }
}

class school
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<student> Students {get; set; }
}

student student1 = new student();
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(student1.School != null ? (student1.School.Name != null ? student1.School.Name : "n/a") : "n/a"); `

Comment: you mentioned some attributes in your answer. Can you please use them